# Importing variable number of columns into SQLite database

Tags: import, sqlite

I have a list of synonyms in a `csv` file format: `word,meaning1,meaning2,meaning3....`

Different words have different number of synonyms which means that rows are likely to have a variable number of columns. I am trying to import the csv file into an sqlite database like so:

```
    sqlite3 synonyms
    sqlite> create table list(word text, meaning0 text, meaning1 text, meaning2 text, meaning3 text, meaning4 text, meaning5 text, meaning6 text, meaning7 text, meaning8 text, meaning9 text);
sqlite> .mode list
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .import ./csv/synonyms.csv list
```

To be on the safe side, I assumed a max. number of 10 columns to each word. For those words with less than 10 synonyms, the other columns should be `null`. The error I get on executing the `import` command is:

```
Error: ./csv/synonyms.csv line 1: expected 11 columns of data but found 3
```

My question(s):
1. In case the number of columns is less than 10, how can I tell `SQLite` to substitute it with `null`?
2. Is there some way of specifying that I want 10 columns after word instead of typing it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following:

- Import all data into single column;
- Update table splitting column contents into other columns.

Sample:

```
-- Create a table with only one column;
CREATE TABLE table_name(first);
-- Choose a separator which doesn't exist within file
.separator ~
-- Import data
.import file.csv table_name

-- Add another column to split data
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN second;
-- Split data between first and second column
UPDATE table_name SET first=SUBSTR(first, 1, INSTR(first, ",")-1), second=SUBSTR(first, INSTR(first, ",")+1) WHERE INSTR(first, ",")>0;

-- Repeat to next column
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN third;
-- Split data between second and third column
UPDATE table_name SET second=SUBSTR(second, 1, INSTR(second, ",")-1), third=SUBSTR(second, INSTR(second, ",")+1) WHERE INSTR(second, ",")>0;

-- And so on...
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN fourth;
UPDATE table_name SET third=SUBSTR(third, 1, INSTR(third, ",")-1), fourth=SUBSTR(third, INSTR(third, ",")+1) WHERE INSTR(third, ",")>0;

-- Many times as needed...
```

Not being an optimal method, [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) performance should render it enough fast.

Comment: error: no such function `INSTR`. I am on a Mac. Any workaround?

Comment: Are you using `sqlite3` shell? Which version?

Comment: SQLite 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41 8f8b373eed7052e6e93c1805fc1effcf1db09366

Comment: Can you upgrade it? `INSTR` was introduced in [2012-12-12](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_15.html)...

Comment: I downloaded `sqlite3` shell from the downloads page of the `sqlite` page. Unzipping it gives me the `sqlite3` shell. WIll replacing it in `/usr/bin` work or are there other dependencies?

Comment: Normally, `SQLite` is self contained. But I'm not a Mac user.